# Converting a pdf into a form ready for binding

Tags: pdf, sorting, printing

I have a pdf that is 118 pages long, and I want to end up with a bindable form, so that I have on one sheet pages:

```
1    4
2    3
```

What is the simplest way in LaTeX to accomplish this?

Would quire work, and if so - how do I go about using it--as I am a bit confused about how to do so. Thanks.

Comment: You may try [pdfpages](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/pdfpages/) to rearrange into a new pdf. See also http://superuser.com/questions/209591/how-to-rearrange-page-in-latex-or-pdf

Comment: After reading that posting, I am still confused as to how to use pdfpages.

Comment: I did however find a post that referred to pdfpages with these commands:                                               \documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages=-,booklet,turn=false,landscape]{mydoc.pdf}
\end{document}                                              and I tried that, but am uncertain if that is **exactly** the format I need. Help please. Thanks.

Comment: With the set of commands I just listed, do I need to have my original document set to **\twosided**? Thanks.

Comment: I think you will get a problem with the booklet option. Your document has 118 pages, so you need 47 sheets. It will be hard to fold them. - more in my [answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/48188/6563).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your front side of the sheet is:

```
1    4
```

and the back side is

```
2    3
```

Then this may be the solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
\includepdf[signature=1,pages=-,landscape]{mydoc.pdf}
\end{document}
```

With other values of `signature` you may build bigger portions of sheets.

With `\includepdf[signature=32,pages=-,landscape]{mydoc.pdf}` you collect 32 pages into one signature. One signature has 8 sheets - you can fold them quite easy. Now you must bind the 
8 signatures to a book.

Comment: so when i do this (as above) how do i get the document two-sided; A) Do i need to put **\twosided** for the document class? and B) I assume I need to run the pages through the printer twice??? Thanks.

Comment: You have to run the pages through the printer twice or you use a printer with double side feature. The `twoside`-option is not obligatory, but I would recommend it. You could use `\includepdf[signature=32,pages=1-4,landscape]{mydoc.pdf}` to print one sheet. You can fold it it compare the difference with and without `twoside`. Which class do you use? `book` is already twoside.

Comment: Thanks, knut I think that answers my question. BTW could I adjust the number after signature, say to a slightly smaller multiple of 4? Thanks again.

Comment: i.e. how can i reduce the number of blank pages??? Thanks so much.

Comment: I am ending up with over 10 blank pages and am not sure how to get rid of them.

Comment: You may adjust the number of pages for the signature. Maby, that also reduce the number of blank pages. I don't know where the come from, but perhaps it is a result of filling up the last signature? You have 118 pages, 4 * 32 is 128. The differnce is 10.

Comment: One last thing: when i do the *pdfpages* the font shrinks about 4 times (from 12 pt to 8 pt) -- how can i turn this off??? Thanks.